# Facebook notification of Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Is there a way of sending notification about new wordpress-based blog to facebook account?
Or maybe a plugin for wordpress?

Restriction is that user shouldn't be logged into facebook, just specify facebook credentials to the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but... just grab your RSS feed and put it here:

http://www.facebook.com/home.php#/editnotes.php?import

Whenever you post it will show up in your notes.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to your wordpress admin page, click Dashboard, select my blogs from the drop down menu.  This gives your blogs, publicise, click facebook, twitter etc, you will need to authorise the link.  All new posts will then be posted on yr fb/ twitter accounts also.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Wordpress.com Facebook application: http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2007/07/18/facebook/

Comment: this is opposite :)
what I am looking for is a way to send status from wordpress to facebook, not post to wordpress from facebook

Comment: It won't work if you host your own WordPress instance as well.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin sounds like it will publish to a Facebook page:
http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/facepress

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. From what I've researched, one of the ways to do this would be to create a Facebook Connect app (which is NOT a full facebook app). If user decides he/she wishes to grant your website/blog permission to connect to the FB account you will be able to post notifications to their wall, etc.

Resources:
http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php

If you're using ASP .NET:
http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit

Answer (score 0):

[WordBook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbook/) is exactly what you want!

Answer (score 0):

How do I import entries from an external blog?
Facebook allows you to quickly and easily import an external blog from another website.
On the Notes page, click the Import a blog link on the right side of the page.
Enter the URL (web address) of your blog into the text box, and check the box underneath that states that you agree to our Terms of Use.
To complete the process, click on "Save Settings." Once you do this, your previous posts will appear as notes and any new posts you make will automatically display.